# Deploying Phonegap / Cordova app for Android?

Tags: android, deployment, build, cordova, command-line-interface

I've got a Phonegap/Cordova 3.0 app that I am testing on Android.

Since version 2.x, Cordova relies heavily on the command-line terminal. I've done all the setup stuff and I can build the app. But two things are troubling me.

First of all, an Android project has two www folders. One is [myproject]/www. The other is [myproject]/platforms/android/assets/www. I'm not sure which of these folders to edit when I am fixing bugs.

If I am correct, the first one is where you place your app files before using the command-line "cordova build" to create the app. The second one should then be only a copy that's used after building, before deploying.

Now my question is, when I make a change to my app and I want to test on device, do I have to use the command line to (re)build the app every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[myproject]/www` is the directory in which you should put your source files.  When you build your app these files are copied in to `[myproject]/platforms/[platform]/assets/www`.  In addition to this, files in `[myproject]/platforms/[platform]` are also copied to `[myproject]/platforms/[platform]/assets/www`, which allows you to create per-platform overrides to your files.

Note that you should **never** edit files in `[myproject]/platforms/[platform]/assets/www` directly, as they will be deleted next time you build your project.

To run your project on your device use `cordova run [platform]`, or to run it on an emulator use `cordova emulate [platform]`.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution: in command-line terminal, type `cordova run android` and the app will be built, deployed and run on device.

Answer (score 0):

Hi First  thing : **Edit www folder inside the asset folder**.
   Second : **no need of command line build** , you can take build via eclipse its very easy, Right click on project root folder --> Run As -> Android Application

Comment: You're right there Arjun, but won't those files be overwritten next time I build using the command-line? It doesn't seem like the right solution.