# Install Sencha Touch 2 application on android device without using google play store

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to install Sencha Touch 2 application on android device without using google play store? Currently I am studying Sencha Touch 2 and want to use applications made during the study. Thank you in advance for any guidance and recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test it then you can use PhoneGap Build to build your app, which is the easiest way. After you build your app, you will see a QR code that can be scanned on a phone and gives you an URL to download the app. Remember that you have to do this for all devices, which need your application to be installed in.

Another option is Cordova, which is the build engine used by PhoneGap and PhoneGap Build. You can find a lot of guidelines for that. For example, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466397/912016

And the third option is to use MDM but it's only if you want to side-load the app to many devices without publishing to Google Play market (e.g. private enterprise app). If it is your case that take a look at AirWatch and Mobile Iron. But I don't think you need it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I use [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/products/gapdebug/) to debug and install my apps. After building my native app I install the `CordovaApp-debug.apk` which can be found in `cordova\platforms\android\ant-build`, after I connect my devices to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Code sign the .apk and email it to an account you can access on your android mobile device, then open the email and tap the .apk file to install.
2. Use ADT adb tool. See [Install an apk file from command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076240/install-an-apk-file-from-command-prompt)

Comment: Thanks man.  I love SO. I receive this hint when traveling.  :)